# Cython compilation warning incompatible types

Tags: cython

I am trying to use a c DLL in cython and during the compilation phase I get a warning from the C compiler :

> `warning C4133: "=" : incompatible types - from 'foobar *' to 'foobar *'`.

My pxd looks like this :

```cython
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#cython: language_level=3

cdef extern from "typedef.h"
    struct foobar:
        long *index
        double *my_array
        int value

cdef extern from "functions.h"
    
    foobar *get_foobar(char *name);
```

And my pyx like that :

```cython
cimport pxd_file_name

cdef class Handler:
    cdef pxd_file_name.foobar *__foobar

    def load_foobar(self, char *name):
        self.__foobar = pxd_file_name.get_foobar(name) <==

    def another_method(self):
        pass
```

I got the warning because of the line marked by an arrow and I don't understand why.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to found my mistake.

Because in my .h file, my struct was declared using typedef, I had to write `ctypedef struct foobar` instead of `struct foobar` in my pxd file